# Extracting data from BSEG table in SAP by period

Tags: sql, sap-erp

I'm looking to extract data from BSEG table in SAP by time.

The problem is that BSEG doesn't hold the time, so I'm told that the work around is to extract all the document numbers for the period I'm after from BKPF into Excel, then extract all document numbers that exist in BSEG and
the Excel.

I'm not familiar with SAP, but isn't there a faster way to get the invoices from BSEG?

In SQL, it would look something like this:

```
select * from BSEG
where doc_num in (select doc_num from BKPF
                  where date between '2010-01-01' and '2014-06-30')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Extracting data from BKPF and BSEG is a huge task. Depending on the quantity of data it could take you a lot of time. Check if the date field you'll use is index. By the way, using the IN statement is a performance killer.

Comment: Thanks. Re IN statement, what do you then suggest?

Comment: The statement "using the IN statement is a performance killer" without any further knowledge of the actual situation is just wrong.

Comment: As for the original question - have you checked whether there are any standard reports that you could use? Extracting data is a complex task if you're interested in consistent results - you have to know a lot about cancellation flags, posting types and whatnot. Are you sure you want to re-invent this particular wheel?

Comment: Just for clarification: the IN statement often causes performance problems in ABAP coding (the IN keyword exists in ABAP Open SQL but it works with an internal table and lots of queries to the database) but not the way it is used here (as an SQL statement that would be executed by the database in one go).